# Why does this.state.items.filter removes an item from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I know how to remove an item from an array within react, but i do not understand the logic behind why this works.

```
removeItem(id) => {
   items:[...this.state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id)]
}
```

All i understand is that if  `item.id !== id` remove the item. But how does this work though ? Why does it remove an item from an array.

Comment: return all items whose item id is not equal to id.

Comment: filter is a js feature not react, it returns a new array that fits the condition `item.id !== id`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation, the following operations are performed

1. Filter the array based on some conditions

Consider the following example

```js
// Defining array
const items = [{"id" : 1},{"id" : 2}, {"id" : 3} ]

//Eliminating id 2
const filteredArray = items.filter(item => item.id !== 2)

console.log(filteredArray)
```

In the above example what filter does is, it returns an array excluding whatever is mentioned in the condition in Our case it's `item.id !== id` so Object having Id 2 is skipped.

Once that is done, items now hold the updated array of object.